# Eigenvalues of Matrix Riccati Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the Matrix Riccati Equation

$$ PA + A^TP + PRP + Q = 0, $$

with positive definite matrices $Q, R$, i.e. $Q = Q^T > 0$, $R = R^T > 0$ and a negative definite $A$, i.e. $A = A^T < 0$. Then, there is a positive definite solution $P = P^T >0$.

Let $R$ be identity matrices and $A = -R$ for simplicity. What can we say about the maximum eigenvalue of the solution $P$ in dependence of the choice of $Q$?

More precisely, is it possible to say that $\lambda_{\max}(P)\leq \lambda_{\max}(Q) $?

Maybe anyone can give a hint about relations of eigenvalues in this content.

Comment: If $R=I_n$ and $A=-R=-I_n$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of dimension $n\times n$, then the equation reads as $P^2-2P+Q=0$. Do you ask about this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that we are talking about the equation
$$ P^2-2P+Q=0. \tag1 $$
If 
$$ Q=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \tfrac{3}{4} & 0 \\ 0 & \tfrac{3}{4}\end{array} \right), $$
then
$$P=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \tfrac{3}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \tfrac{1}{2}\end{array} \right)$$
is a solution of (1). Note that the maximal eigenvalue of $P$ is greater than the eigenvalue of $Q$.

Comment: Thank you for this counterexample. I did not consider the simplification when i set $R$ = $I_n$ and $A = - I_n$. Actually, in my problem i can choose for all matrices any reasonable values. However, i don't know how to choose $A,R,Q$ that $\lambda_{\max}(P)\leq \lambda_{\max}(Q)$. Is there a condition (maybe a lemma or theorem) for eigenvalues $P$ in dependence of $Q$ and $R$? (I suppose that, normally $R$ and $Q$ can be selected, and $A$ is fixed since it might describes a dynamical system.) A reference may be also helpful.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Matrix Riccati Equation, so I cannot recommend references. However if you are looking for an example such that $\lambda_{max}(P)\leq \lambda_{max}(Q)$, then you can take as before $R=I$, $A=-I$ and $Q=diag[2\lambda_1-\lambda_{1}^{2},\ldots, 2\lambda_n-\lambda_{n}^{2}]$, where $0\leq \lambda_i \leq 1$. Then the solution is $P=diag[\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n]$. For this example one has $\lambda_i \leq 2\lambda_i-\lambda_{i}^{2}$ (line $y=x$ in on the interval $[0,1]$ below the parabola $y=2x-x^2$).